# Mocking a repository that returns optional is always returning Optional.empty in the Unit Test

Tags: java, spring, mockito, junit5

I am using java 17, spring 3.0.5 and junit 5 and mockito
It works correctly from the test class:

```
@SpringBootTest
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class TaskApplicationTests {

    @MockBean
    private MerchantRepository merchantRepository;
    
    @MockBean
    private TransactionRepository transactionRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private MerchantService merchantService;
    
    @Autowired
    private TransactionService transactionService;
    
    @BeforeAll
    public void loadContext() {
        Merchant loggedInUser = new Merchant();
        loggedInUser.setEmail("loggedInUser@email.com");
        Optional<Merchant> loggedInOptional = Optional.of(loggedInUser);
when(merchantRepository.findByEmail(loggedInUser.getEmail())).thenReturn(loggedInOptional);
System.out.println("user: "+merchantRepository.findByEmail(loggedInUser.getEmail())); //user is returned correctly from loadContext method
    }


    @Test
    void testMethod() {
        System.out.println("user: "+merchantRepository.findByEmail("loggedInUser@email.com")); //outputs Optional.empty from test method
    }
}
```

Why is the @Test method having a different result?

Any reason why that could happen?

Comment: So the mocked test code works but the production code doesn't? Then the problem must be in the production code.... which you haven't shown.

Comment: The application is working fine on production. I mean when I run junit tests. the result of the mock is different in the test class and service class. it's just a sysout that shows the difference. The service layer always returns Optional.empty

Comment: Then the problem is probably in the Service class

Comment: there isn't much in the service layer. just autowiring the merchantRepository and printing the line System.out.println("user: "+merchantRepository.findByEmail("loggedInUser@email.com")); to see what is returning. It returns Optional.empty which is different from expected. I expect loggedInOptional as mocked

Comment: Are you mocking the Service too? It won't just magically use the mocked response from the repository.

Comment: no. I am autowiring the service. It appears in the code. I want to mock the repository only (the database layer). I will perform the unit tests on the service layer

Comment: Right, so it must be in the Service. Place some breakpoints, attach a debugger and find out.

Comment: you should show us the actual service method the second sout doesn´t make any sense in any context

Comment: The author does not understand what he is asking about, read general documentation about junit test first.

Comment: what do you mean with this `However, it doesn't work correctly from the service layer (in merchantService for instance)`  ?  if you run normally and you dont have the merchant in the db it will return Optional.empty the reason it work in the Test is because you are mocking the return value and you are not even testing the service with the code you show us you are testing merchantRepository in the method loadContext() with a sout

Comment: How does `MerchantService` get hold of the `MerchantRepository`? Is the repository instance in the test the same instance as in the service? You can use a debugger to find out.

Comment: I edited the question after more investigation. Actually, the merchantRepository mock is giving different result inside the test class. The results are different in the loadContext method and test method. So, it's not about the service layer. It is something in the unit test

Comment: You have not answered the question that @knittl asked. Also, I would simplify things by not using `@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)`.

Answer (score -2):

The answer is pretty obvious, in the real flow(not test one), namely merchantRepository is not able to find anything by email given. So you have to make sure if it is present within the final source(database/3rd party service). If it is present then provide with more details please, test class does not have anything common with the real application data.

Comment: The OP is talking about getting a different answer from what they think should be the same mock at two points in their test.

Comment: The OP does not understand junit testing concept at all, most likely he is trying to copy-past something without understanding

Comment: I see two code samples in the question, the first is a junit test and the second is an implementation of an interface, the question itself is ' it doesn't work correctly from the service layer (in merchantService for instance), Any reason why that could happen?' So, @tgdavies, why the answer is downvoted?

Comment: `MerchantServiceImpl` is the class being tested, and the OP expects it to have had the mock `MerchantRepository` injected into it. The mistake they have made is most likely that they have not injected the mock, but they have not yet shown enough code to enable anyone to help them. You seem to be suggesting that they fix the problem by putting the test data in the DB, but that's not the right solution. They are not interested in the real flow, just their tests.

Comment: The question at present is ambiguous and unanswerable. I don't think anyone could write a valuable answer at this point.

Comment: Yes, I downvoted because the answer is not a useful answer to the question.

Comment: Indeed, maintaining the quality of SO is self affirmation, I suppose. As you can see from my comments on the question, I am trying to find out what is actually going on, so that the question can be answered correctly.